# sharepoint list jquery javascript

Tags: list, javascript

I have checkbox field "Department" with values ( De beers, Platinum, gold, silver) and another single line of text "Design". When any user select "De beers" from checkbox, then "Design" field should get mandatory and user could not submit the form. Please let me know if any javascript of jquery is available. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Jquery you will implement you requirement.

Code :

```
if($('input[name="De beers"]:checked'))
{
$("#Design").attr("required", "true");
}
```

Comment: Where this jQuery code be placed?

Comment: Design field need to be required if only Department = De beers, for rest value of department Design field need to be non required.

Comment: You have to place this jquery in Jslink .

Answer (score 1):

What about no script at all and putting *something like* this Formula in the Validation settings:

```
=IF( AND( [Department]="De Beers" , ISBLANK([Design]) ) , FALSE , TRUE )
```

So SharePoint does what it can do